# Como imprimir un arreglo con recursividad en Java

Tags: java

Muy buenos días a todos ustedes,

Estoy tratando de sacar la raíz cuadrada de un arreglo usando: `el método de newton` y `recursividad`. y tengo problemas con imprimir la salida. Espero que me ayuden a identificar el problema.

*Lo que entiendo por recursividad es que el método debe llamarse a si mismo varias veces hasta completar el arreglo para luego hacer el return hacia el* **segundo método** *ya que es allí donde se imprimirán todas las salidas.*

edit:
Al parecer el **segundo método está duplicado**.  Según el docente debería reutilizar el código del **primer método** en el **segundo método**.

Me podrían explicar como hacerlo?

**primer metodo:**

```
    public static double calcularRaiz(int x) {
        var estimacion = x / 2.0;
        var cociente = 0.0;
        var contador = 0;
        do{
            cociente = x / estimacion;
            estimacion = (cociente + estimacion) / 2.0;
            contador = contador + 1;
        }while (contador < 10);
        return estimacion;
    }
```

**segundo método:**

```
   public static double[] calcularRaizNewtonArreglo(int[] x) {
        var estimacion = x.length / 2.0;
        var cociente = 0.0;
        var contador = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
            estimacion = x[i] / 2.0;
            do {
                cociente = x[i] / estimacion;
                estimacion = (cociente + estimacion) / 2.0;
                contador = contador + 1;
            } while (contador < 10);
            // he hecho varias pruebas en este método, pero no logro hacer que imprima
            System.out.print ("La raiz de " + x[i] + " es: " + estimacion);
        }
        if (estimacion > 0){
            calcularRaizCuadradaNewtonArreglo(estimacion);
            // y tampoco se si esto llamado recursividad está bien o no
        }
        return estimacion;
    }
```

**tercer método:**

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int numero = 2;
        System.out.println("La raiz de " + numero + " es: " + calcularRaizCuadrada(numero));

        int[] array = {2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20};
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            System.out.print ("La raiz de " + array[i] + " es: " + calcularRaizCuadradaNewtonArreglo(array));
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hola @lucho, no se si será correcto preguntar aquí en un comentario, pero me bajé tu código para probarlo y me da error en los "var", me puedes decir que son ? gracias

Comment: @Joseba debe estar usando la librería Lombock o alguna otra similar que permite la creación de las var. o puede que esté usando el JDK10. Puedes mirar el siguiente enlace. https://www.arquitecturajava.com/java-var-keyword-y-su-uso-con-jdk10/#:~:text=El%20concepto%20de%20Java%20var,de%20tipos%20sobre%20nuestras%20variables.

Comment: @Joseba
Estoy usando el **jdk-15.0.2** con editor **IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2020.3.3**
Saludos

Answer (score 5, accepted):

respondiendo a tu pregunta, se observa un poco de confunsión al respecto.

Cuando te hablan de la recursividad en tu caso, se refiere a reutilización de código, pero esto no quiere decir que se esté refiriendo a hacer la recursividad de una función como tal.

Empecemos analizando los bloques de código que aportas y sus respectivos ajustes:

```
    /* Esta funcion realiza algo de manera redundante.
       Ya que se realiza un ciclo de repetición que siempre va a estar dando el mismo resultado.
       La única variable que tiene cambios es el contador
    */
    public static double calcularRaizCuadrada(int x) {
    var estimacion = x / 2.0;
    var cociente = 0.0;
    var contador = 0;
    do{
        cociente = x / estimacion;
        estimacion = (cociente + estimacion) / 2.0;
        contador = contador + 1;
    }while (contador < 10);
    return estimacion;
}
```

En otras palabras, lo que estás haciendo en la función `calcularRaizCuadrada`, sería lo mismo que te expresaré:

```
    public static double calcularRaizCuadrada(int x) {
    var estimacion = x / 2.0;
    // var cociente = 0.0;
    // var contador = 0;

    var cociente = x / estimacion;
    estimacion = (cociente + estimacion) / 2.0;

    // do{
    //   contador = contador + 1;
    // }while (contador < 10);
    return estimacion;
}
```

De esta manera quedaría de manera más optima nuestra función `calcularRaizCuadrada`. Ahora procedamos a revisar el siguiente bloque de código que expones:

```
/* Esta funcion a diferencia de la función revisada anteriormente,
   tiene un ciclo for para recorrer el arreglo de tipo entero que recibe como parámetro.
   Pero lo que se desea realizar es exactamente igual que la función `calcularRaizCuadrada`.
   Solo que se le realiza a cada elemento del arreglo.
   Por ende tiene redundancia en este código como se mencionó en la función anterior
   y procesos innecesarios.

   Otra cosa que se observa es que se recorre el arreglo aqui, se imprimen sus valores y se hace el retorno del último valor. Esto estaría mal.
*/
public static double calcularRaizCuadradaNewtonArreglo(int[] x) {
    var estimacion = x.length / 2.0;
    var cociente = 0.0;
    var contador = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        estimacion = x[i] / 2.0;
        do {
            cociente = x[i] / estimacion;
            estimacion = (cociente + estimacion) / 2.0;
            contador = contador + 1;
        } while (contador < 10);
        // he hecho varias pruebas en este método, pero no logro hacer que imprima
        System.out.print ("La raiz de " + x[i] + " es: " + estimacion);
    }

    /* Este condicional es innecesario y la funcion marcaría error,
       Debido a que recibe un arreglo de enteros y no un double
    */
    if (estimacion > 0){
        calcularRaizCuadradaNewtonArreglo(estimacion);
        // y tampoco se si esto llamado recursividad está bien o no
    }
    return estimacion;
}
```

Teniendo claro lo que se acaba de mencionar, hay dos posibles formas. La primera y mas sencilla, sería la siguiente:

```
public static void calcularRaizCuadradaNewtonArreglo(int[] x) {
    // var estimacion = x.length / 2.0;
    // var cociente = 0.0;
    // var contador = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        // estimacion = x[i] / 2.0;
        // do {
        //      cociente = x[i] / estimacion;
        //      estimacion = (cociente + estimacion) / 2.0;
        //      contador = contador + 1;
        // } while (contador < 10);

        System.out.println("La raiz de " + x[i] + " es: " + calcularRaizCuadrada(x[i]));
    }
    // if (estimacion > 0){
    //      calcularRaizCuadradaNewtonArreglo(estimacion);
    // }
    // return estimacion;
}
```

Como puedes observar, la función quedó recorriendo el arreglo mediante el ciclo for e imprimiendo la información que requerías de la raiz cuadrada de cada item del arreglo. El calculo se hace mediante la función `calcularRaizCuadrada`

La otra opción, es retornando un arreglo con los valores de la raiz cuadrada, de cada elemento del arreglo suministrado, esto en caso tal de que necesites tener el retorno y poder manipular la información obtenida fuera de la función. Podría hacerse de la siguiente manera:

```
public static double[] calcularRaizCuadradaNewtonArreglo2(int[] x) {

    double[] res = new double[x.length];

    for(int i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        res[i] = calcularRaizCuadrada(x[i]);
    }

    return res;
}
```

Ya para finalizar procedemos a revisar el metodo Main:

```
/* Se observa que recorres el arreglo para mandarle varias veces a la funcion `calcularRaizCuadradaNewtonArreglo` mandandole el mismo arreglo.
   Ya tienes el for recorriendo el arreglo en dicha función así que puedes omitir recorrerlo como lo haces cuando llamas la funcion en el Main.

  Hay 2 opciones, realizar el for dentro de la funcion como lo planteaste
  procedes a llamar a la funcion en el main sin el for.

  Otra opcion es dejar el for en el main,
  en ves de llamar a la funcion `calcularRaizCuadradaNewtonArreglo`
  mejor llamas la primer funcion y le mandas como parametro cada elemento del arreglo.
  Es decir `calcularRaizCuadrada(array[i])`
*/
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int numero = 2;
    System.out.println("La raiz de " + numero + " es: " + calcularRaizCuadrada(numero));

    int[] array = {2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20};
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        System.out.print ("La raiz de " + array[i] + " es: " + calcularRaizCuadradaNewtonArreglo(array));
    }
}
```

Procedo a dejarte las alternativas de como podrías tener el main basandonos en los ajustes sugeridos:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String saltoLinea = System.getProperty("line.separator");
    int numero = 4;
    System.out.println("La raiz de " + numero + " es: " + calcularRaizCuadrada(numero));
    
    System.out.println(saltoLinea + ":::::::::::: FORMA 1 usando calcularRaizCuadradaNewtonArreglo ::::::::::::");
    System.out.println(saltoLinea);
    
    int[] array = {2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20};
    
    // Ejecutar forma 1
    calcularRaizCuadradaNewtonArreglo(array);
    
    System.out.println(saltoLinea + ":::::::::::: FIN ::::::::::::");
    System.out.println(":::::::::::: FORMA 2 usando calcularRaizCuadradaNewtonArreglo2 ::::::::::::" + saltoLinea);
    
    // Ejecutar forma 2
    double[] res = calcularRaizCuadradaNewtonArreglo2(array);
    for (int i = 0; i < res.length; i++) {
        System.out.println("La raiz de " + array[i] + " es: " + res[i]);
    }
    
    System.out.println(saltoLinea + ":::::::::::: FIN ::::::::::::");
    System.out.println(":::::::::::: FORMA 3 usando calcularRaizCuadrada ::::::::::::" + saltoLinea);
    
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        System.out.println("La raiz de " + array[i] + " es: " + calcularRaizCuadrada(array[i]));
    }
    
    System.out.println(saltoLinea + ":::::::::::: FIN ::::::::::::");
}
```

El Main que te propongo, tiene todas las formas que te sugerí. La más optima sería aplicar la forma 3. Para que realices la prueba te comparto todo el código como quedaría

```
public class CalcularRaizCuadrada {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    String saltoLinea = System.getProperty("line.separator");
    int numero = 4;
    System.out.println("La raiz de " + numero + " es: " + calcularRaizCuadrada(numero));
    
    System.out.println(saltoLinea + ":::::::::::: FORMA 1 usando calcularRaizCuadradaNewtonArreglo ::::::::::::");
    System.out.println(saltoLinea);
    
    int[] array = {2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20};
    
    // Ejecutar forma 1
    calcularRaizCuadradaNewtonArreglo(array);
    
    System.out.println(saltoLinea + ":::::::::::: FIN ::::::::::::");
    System.out.println(":::::::::::: FORMA 2 usando calcularRaizCuadradaNewtonArreglo2 ::::::::::::" + saltoLinea);
    
    // Ejecutar forma 2
    double[] res = calcularRaizCuadradaNewtonArreglo2(array);
    for (int i = 0; i < res.length; i++) {
        System.out.println("La raiz de " + array[i] + " es: " + res[i]);
    }
    
    System.out.println(saltoLinea + ":::::::::::: FIN ::::::::::::");

    // Ejecutar forma 3
    System.out.println(":::::::::::: FORMA 3 usando calcularRaizCuadrada ::::::::::::" + saltoLinea);
    
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        System.out.println("La raiz de " + array[i] + " es: " + calcularRaizCuadrada(array[i]));
    }
    
    System.out.println(saltoLinea + ":::::::::::: FIN ::::::::::::");
}

/**
 * Ejecucion funcion en la forma 3 del ejemplo
 * @param x
 * @return
 */
public static double calcularRaizCuadrada(int x) {
    var estimacion = x / 2.0;
    var cociente = x / estimacion;

    return (cociente + estimacion) / 2.0;
}

/**
 * Ejecucion metodo en la forma 1 del ejemplo
 * @param x
 */
public static void calcularRaizCuadradaNewtonArreglo(int[] x) {
    for (int i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        System.out.println("La raiz de " + x[i] + " es: " + calcularRaizCuadrada(x[i]));
    }
}

/**
 * Ejecucion funcion en la forma 2 del ejemplo
 * @param x
 * @return
 */
public static double[] calcularRaizCuadradaNewtonArreglo2(int[] x) {

    double[] res = new double[x.length];

    for(int i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        res[i] = calcularRaizCuadrada(x[i]);
    }

    return res;
}
}
```

Una ultima cosa, en ves de usar `System.out.print(...)` usa `System.out.println(...)`, para que cada impresion que haga en la consola, la haga en una linea nueva y no se corrido

Espero haber sido claro. Saludos.

Comment: No me esperaba algo tan detallado. Realmente usted despejó todas mis dudas. Muchas gracias por haber comentado

Comment: Vaya!!!, impresionante respuesta y clase magistral. Te felicito @jorgeGomez

Comment: @el.trasgu muchas gracias